# What is the default line spacing in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I want to increase the default line spacing in `UITextView` by 10 units.

Here's how I am doing:

```
NSDictionary *attributesDictionary;
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 30;

attributesDictionary = @{NSParagraphStyleAttributeName : paragraphStyle , NSFontAttributeName: cellFont};

[str addAttributes:attributesDictionary range:NSMakeRange(0, str.length)];
bodyTextView.attributedText = str;
```

So what is the default value that I should add 10 with and set it the linespacing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default value is 0.

This can be shown by creating a `UITextView` with some text and set its font to Helvetica size 12 (which is the default of an `NSAttributedString`). If you then use your code above but set `paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 0` and remove whatever font you're setting in your `attributesDictionary` you can see that the spacing in your `bodyTextView` will be identical to the spacing in the non-attributed version. I am assuming that this holds true with other fonts (such as whatever you're using in `cellFont`)